# Métodos alternativos para armazenamento em Servidor de Aplicação

Tags: java, xml, aplicação-web, cache, jboss

Boa Tarde Pessoal,  gostaria de algumas sugestões de formas alternativas de acesso a dados em um servidor de aplicação, mais especificamente um JBoss 6. Ocorreu que eu possuo uma aplicação hospedada em um JBoss 6 e preciso de tempos em tempos recuperar dados armazenados em BD ou arquivo (como a quantia de dados não é muito grande estou utilizando atualmente a solução de leitura de arquivo). Porém com certeza a leitura frequente ao arquivo e/ou consulta ao BD, além de consumir memória, também afeta o desempenho do sistema. Saberiam de alguma forma alternativa de leitura aos dados ? Por ex, alguma forma de manter os dados lidos de BD/arquivo em memória (Cache) ? Somente esclarecendo, a leitura ao arquivo/BD é feita de tempos em tempos, por ex de 2 em 2 horas,e é necessário que um projeto web tenha a informação disponível a todo momento. Alguma sugestão ?
 Só para constar,  o projeto web em questão é este aqui:  http://allinyourhandsweb.com  Resultado de um projeto meu de cerca de 8 meses de desenvolvimento, fiquem a vontade para qualquer sugestão referente ao mesmo.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Cache em memória é bastante comum. Você pode usar ferramentas como:

- [Memcached](http://memcached.org/): usado pelo Youtube e Wikipedia. Funciona com diversas plataformas e não só Java. Independe de um servidor de aplicação.
- [Apache Java Cache Systems](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/): implementação em Java de um sistema de cache em memória.
- [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/): outra implementação em Java, mantida por uma empresa que oferece outros produtos relacionados, caso você necessite de mais capacidade.

Em geral, todos esses sistemas de cache funcionam em um ou mais servidores de forma distribuída. São processos (programas) a parte que a aplicação acessa via comunicação entre processos ou algum outro protocolo configurável.

As implementações em Java podem também ser colocadas embutidas na aplicação, porém isso faz com que se perca a vantagem da distribuição e da durabilidade dos dados no caso de reinicialização da aplicação.

Outra alternativa é usar um banco de dados em memória, como o [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com), um *fork* do MySQL.

O MySQL possui diferentes mecanismos que você pode usar para gerenciar as tabelas, por exemplo, o InnoDB e o MyISAM. Cada mecanismo possui características, capacidades e restrições diferentes.

O MariaDB estende essas funcionalidades e possui outras *engines* de tabelas, como a [***MEMORY storage engine***](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/memory-storage-engine/). Com isso, você pode criar um banco de dados em memória para fazer cache dos dados e ainda aproveitar as mesmas queries usadas nas tabelas "normais", persistidas em disco.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta, utluiz.  Tentei iniciar a implementação utilizando o "Apache Java Cache Systems", no entanto ao subir o jboss percebo um erro relacionado ao TransactionManager. Você teria uma idéia do que poderia ser ?

Comment: @rbertani Assim é muito genérico. É mais fácil o erro de transações estar ligado a configuração do banco de dados. Sugiro que poste outra pergunta aqui no SO com detalhes de configuração e com o trecho de código (método ou classe) onde o erro ocorre, mais as pilhas de erro. Abraço.

Comment: Cara, vou tentar implementar usando "Memcached", me pareceu uma solução melhor. De qualquer forma, se eu descobrir o erro no JCS posto aqui.  Obrigado pelo apoio.